# Can't alter integers sent by spawn from nodeJS to Python

Tags: python, node.js

I was trying how to run python from NodeJS and found the child_proccess spawn solution online.

```
// server setup constant
const express  = require('express');

// The application
const app = express();

// Port the server runs on
const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("running (main.js)"));


const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const py = spawn('python', ['main.py', "Message", 12]);


py.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

py.stdout.on('end', () => {
    console.log("end of transmission");
});
```

The second parameter that I sent is an integer 12. I tried incrementing the number in my python script and then printing it back. The weird thing is, if I alter a String which I have transmitted as an argument from Node to Python, there is no issue. If I try to alter any number Python crashes. Are numbers transmitted as constants and that's why? and if so, how would I work around that?

Python:

```
import sys, json as np

message = sys.argv[1]
number = sys.argv[2]

number = number + 1

print(message)
print("Added one to number")
print(number)


sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list of strings. Use the `int()` function to turn a string to a number.

```
import sys, json as np

message = sys.argv[1]
number = int(sys.argv[2])  # convert string to number

number = number + 1

print(message)
print("Added one to number")
print(number)


sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: That was actually the solution, thank you very much, I was not aware of sys argv being an array of Strings, although I could have guessed since it is one in Java as well. My bad and Thank you very much :)